# Allure Report jenkins setup- Unable to configure java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy

Tags: jenkins, protractor, allure

issue:Configtools/config issue.I cannot even figure it out

[image]

Comment: java arguements needs to be added.but my jenkins is slave.cant  add it here

Answer (score 1):

Add allure reporter to your protractor config file

```
        var AllureReporter = require('jasmine-allure-reporter');
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new AllureReporter());

        jasmine.getEnv().afterEach(function (done) {
        browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (png) {
            allure.createAttachment('Screenshot', function () {
                return new Buffer(png, 'base64')
            }, 'image/png')();
            done();
```

Comment: This configuration you need to enter in your protractor config file

Comment: No,This is in jenkins global setting page.the issue is different

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Tick the Manage jenkins-Configure Global Security-Plugin-manager-use browser for meta download  - and go to manage plugin and update it